# finding out what is causing dreaded "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." message

Tags: drupal, upgrade, drupal-7

while doing a drupal 6 to 7 upgrade I am getting the not so helpful message
"The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." everytime I go to certain pages.
ex) /admin/config

What is the best way to find out what is causing the fatal error so that I can fix it?

All I can think of right now is to start disabling contributed modules until that page works or looking through the logs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By clearing the logs at `/admin/reports/dblog` then reloading the broken page I easily could identify the offending module when I rechecked the log.

Site is working fine now : )

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that when the problem is watchdog, itself, this doesn't work... as I am finding out.

Comment: If you're not logged in you cannot view /admin/reports/dblog, if you log in, you get the error

Answer (score 21):

If dlog/watchdog and php error log aren't working, try this:

go on /includes/error.inc
comment line  line 245

```
print theme('maintenance_page', array('content' => t('The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.')));
```

and put this

```
print theme('maintenance_page', array('content' => t('The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.'.$fatal.' '.var_export($error,true))));
```

Very similar, you put var_export($error,true)) at end of error

Answer (score 3):

You definitely should be disabling all contrib modules to perform the upgrade. 
Then enable them a few at a time after they have been replaced with the D7 version.  When replacing the module, be sure to clean out the entire module directory, just in case some old files remain.

This should help narrow down the problem and be sure to check the php error log in case you find something there.  (Although that is usually in the case of the White Screen Of Death.)

Answer (score 0):

As gyozo mentioned if you are not able to log into the site, then it might be difficult to debug.

Then probably you could try

1. Log into database and run `delete from watchdog;`
2. Refresh the page
3. Then execute the database query `select variables from watchdog;`
4. Look out for the text near message

Answer (score 0):

Am replying on 8 years old thread. But wanted to share my inputs to fix this error. I am using Drupal 8.*

I faced the same error when I tried to clear the cache (From performance). I tried several things mentioned in most of the blogs or drupal help.

In the end I came to know that, there was some YML formatting issue in my Drupal 8 theme files. I removed tabs and validated my YML files from online YML validator.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8.7 you can do this in core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/FinalExceptionSubscriber.php line 126:

```
$content = $this->t('The website encountered an  error. Please try again later.' . var_dump($error));
```