# the website encountered an unexpected error. please try again later. drupal 8

Tags: elasticsearch, drupal-8, elastica

I want configure elasticsearch(ES) with Drupal
to integrate ES in Drupal following this [tutorial](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/indexing-content-from-drupal-8-to-elasticsearch)
In order to install ES followed steps mentioned on this [link](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/local-server-setup/windows-development-environment/quick-install-drupal-with-xampp-on)

```
Drupal-8.8.4
search api version-8.x-1.15
Elasticsearch drupal connector-8.x-6.x,also tried 8.x-7.x but no success
```

After added modules can see this below screenshot
[image]
[image: Elastic search connector]
[image: Search api]

But when I want enable added modules as mentioned in steps,got below error

```
the website encountered an unexpected error. please try again later.
```

[image]

Referred this [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737768/finding-out-what-is-causing-dreaded-the-website-encountered-an-unexpected-error)

Is it due to compability issue or how to resolve issue
any leads will be appreciated?

Comment: can you check elasticsearch logs and provide here?

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja actually yet to add ES cluster details inside drupal. ES is running  fine independently.Also checked ES log no any error over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this answer to support community.
Yes, indeed it was version incompatibility issue between drupal, elastic-search and drupal-elasticsearch connector and search api..
Tried number of combinations by installing modules manually but keep getting  below error.

```
the website encountered an unexpected error. please try again later.
```

Used composer tool to install modules which work exactly like maven in java project.

```
composer require 'drupal/search_api:^add version accordingly'
composer require 'drupal/elasticsearch_connector:^add version accordingly'
```